# How to use suiteQL to query Image field?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suiteql

I had one image field with the id 'custitem_test_img' on the Item record, Item internal id is '1234',
I made one SuiteQL like the below:

```sql
SELECT Item.custitem_test_img FROM Item WHERE Item.id = 1234
```

And I got one error back with a message:

> **Error**: Search error occurred: Field 'custitem_test_img' for record 'item' was not found. Reason: UNSUITABLE - Unsupported data type 'IMAGE'

Any idea how to query the Image type field by SuiteQL?